# Keeping input cursor at end when pressing arrow up and down, Angular Js directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm making a "typeahead/autocomplete" -directive.

```
    element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {

      if(event.which === 38 || event.which === 40) {
        var inc = event.which === 38 ? 1: -1;
        ...
        ...
      };
    });
```

When you click up and down you choose between the filtred items. Problem is the cursor moves back and forth when you use up and down arrow.

I tried to put a element[0].focus() but it didn't help.

Is there any easy way to keep the cursor at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `event.preventDefault()` to stop further processing of the event:

```
element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
  if(event.which === 38 || event.which === 40) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var inc = event.which === 38 ? 1: -1;
    ...
    ...
  };
});
```